# ON CONFLICT operator in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I have a table in Cassandra with 2 columns: id and date_proc and plan to insert a lot of inserts. Is it possible to use something like ON CONFLICT in Postgres to get previous value on inserting?

Could you tell me another way to avoid 2 requests to Cassandra (select and insert)? Maybe some solution in DataStax?

ddl:

```
create table test.date_dict (
    id text,
    date_proc text,
    PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

example of inserting:

```
INSERT INTO test.date_dict (id, date_proc) VALUES ('1', '2020-01-01'); // return '2020-01-01'
INSERT INTO test.date_dict (id, date_proc) VALUES ('1', '2020-01-05'); // return '2020-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Normal" inserts and updates in Cassandra are just appends into the memtable (and then flushed into SSTables) - no read happens during these operations.  And it will just overwrite previous data if it has lower timestamp.

Potentially you can use [lightweight transactions](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_using/useInsertLWT.html) (LWTs) to achieve what you need - they return previous value if there is a conflict (row exists already when you use `IF NOT EXISTS`, or value is different than you specify in the `IF` condition).  But LWTs are very bad for performance, so they should be used carefully.

I would try to reformulate your task such way so it will fit into "normal" inserts/updates behavior.